# Own static linking plugin

Tags: qt, plugins, static, linker

I have plugin and i want static link it with my app.
In plugin.pro file i have:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
```

In plugin.cpp:

```
Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(plugin, pluginClass)
```

Of course TARGET in .pro file is the same as plugin name.

In myapp.pro file:

```
LIBS += libplugin.a
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtPlugin>

Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(plugin)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ...
    return a.exec();
}
```

Plugin compiles without errors, i got *.a and *.o files, so i copied *.a file to myapp directory and when i trying compile i get error like this:

```
cannot find -lmyplugin.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So i gave full path to libplugin.a in myapp.pro file and i got in the line with Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN error:

```
undefined reference to `qt_plugin_instance_plugin()'
```

and much errors like this:

```
undefined reference to `pluginClass::function()'
```

I included *.h file of my plugin.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: IIRC the line in your .pro file should read `LIBS += plugin`, I'm not sure if that'll fix all of your errors, but I bet it'll fix the first linker error.

Comment: @Chris Think this help only with Qt plugins. I have my own plugin, and LIBS += plugin causes: "plugin: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 2):

In your plugin .pro file use this code:

```
CONFIG += plugin static
```

instead of

```
CONFIG += staticlib
```